# What is the best performance of design for my tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, sqlperformance

I have 3 tables that they can be on 1table. What is the best performance for its design?
I need a fast database on search and read, not on insert.

1. These 3 tables will be read too more than be written
2. These 3 tables have more than 5 millions records
3. Most of the fields that are available in this table "p_apartmentbuy" are used in the search clause query (they have been indexed) And include some fields that are shown in the search result
4. The fields in this table "p_apartmentbuydetail" aren't used in search clause
5. "pf_contact" table will be used to show on some search result and usually 
   some columns are null

And what is differences between a "keyname with several indexes" and "several keynames with one index for each one" (like attachment photo).
[image]

```
Relations between tables:
       p_apartmentbuy.id = p_apartmentbuydetail.p_apartmentbuy_id (1:1)
       pf_contact.id = p_apartmentbuydetail.pf_contact_id (1:1)

    CREATE TABLE `p_apartmentbuy` (
      `id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `dateadd` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `sqm` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `age` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `price` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pricemeter` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `bedroom` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `parking` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `storage` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `elevator` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `describe` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `featured` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_source_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `l_location_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `l_city_id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `l_province_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_status_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_floor_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_facing_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_cabinet_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_service_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `dateadd` (`dateadd`),
      KEY `sqm` (`sqm`),
      KEY `age` (`age`),
      KEY `price` (`price`),
      KEY `bedroom` (`bedroom`),
      KEY `parking` (`parking`),
      KEY `storage` (`storage`),
      KEY `elevator` (`elevator`),
      KEY `l_location_id` (`l_location_id`),
      KEY `l_city_id` (`l_city_id`),
      KEY `l_province_id` (`l_province_id`),
      KEY `pricemeter` (`pricemeter`),
      FULLTEXT KEY `describe` (`describe`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE `pf_contact` (
      `id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `mobile` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `telephone` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `telephone2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE `p_apartmentbuydetail` (
      `p_apartmentbuy_id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `link` varchar(999) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
      `sqmland` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `floortotal` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `floorno` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `unitno` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `unitperfloor` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `remotedoor` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `iphone` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `trase` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `sona` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pool` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `jackosi` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `renovate` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `tel` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `water` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `gas` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `electricity` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_kitchen_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_contact_id` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_temperaturesystem_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pf_position_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `prev_id` smallint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`p_apartmentbuy_id`),
      KEY `prev_id` (`prev_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: The performance on read will depend on the indexes that you create on the tables. The indexes that should be created depend in turn on the kind of queries you will be making, paying special attention to what is expected to appear in a typical WHERE and ORDER BY clauses in your queries.